# Get data from a Dataset by parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: asp.net, dataset, datasource, asp.net-4.0

I'm following a tutorial where they explain how to add a `Dataset` to your ASP.NET web application and how to add a parameter to a `SQL` query. But it's not really working for me the way they are doing it in the tutorial.

I've added a `Dataset` to my `App_Code` folder. In the dataset i made a connection to a database in SQL Server. Now i can get data from my database by giving the dataset a `SQL query`. In the tutorial they do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 20 [ProductID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[ProductNumber]
      ,[MakeFlag]
      ,[FinishedGoodsFlag]
      ,[Color]
      ,[SafetyStockLevel]
FROM [Production].[Product]
WHERE (Color = :Color)
```

The point in this example is the `:Color` part. That is how they let it know where to add the parameter. But when i use this query in my `Dataset` it gives me a warning:

> Error in WHERE clause near ':'. Unable to parse query text.

After that he is able to actually add a parameter to the `Dataset` through the `Properties` window and test preview his data. That doesn't work for me since it already starts to complain when i add my query.

What can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in Sql-Server have a `@` in front:

```
WHERE (Color = @Color)
```

[Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick :) Accepting in 5 min (when i'm allowed to)